# Build Project > How to checkout different repositories in different folders

Tags: teamcity

I am new to TeamCity. I have my projects in different repositories. I want to checkout my projects in Different subfolders. e.g.

Lets suppose that I have following 3 .net Projects in three different projects.

> Framework
>
> XYZ
>
> MyProject

Each project is stored in its own repository. MyProject contains a solution file, which expects that Framwork and XYZ Projects Folders are in main Folder so that the Folder structure looks like that

> +FrameWork
>
> ```
>  -ProjectFile
>  -.........
> ```
>
> +XYZ
>
> ```
>  -ProjectFile
> ```
>
> +MyProject
>
> ```
>  -SolutionFile(has references of both Projects.)
> ```

Now my problem is I want to checkout my projects from different repositories in own Folders. How to configure it in TeamCity.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You would need to configure each VCS Root in Version Control Settings. For each root, you can 
specify what folders are of interest to you with the Checkout Rules. When creating the checkout rules, you have the option to leave the folder structure the same as it is in your VCS or you can remap the struture to suit your needs.

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/2.Version+Control+Settings

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/VCS+Checkout+Rules

In Order to solve the given problem. Following checkout Rules need to be applied on corresponding version control root.

```
+:.=>FrameWork
+:.=>XYZ
+:.=>MyProject
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Its working fine but I could't get any artifact. I have following configuration 

Artifact paths:- /MyProject/bin/Release/*.* => PublishDir

Build Runner : Visual Studio(sln)
Build file path: \Successor\Successor.sln
Targets: Rebuild
Configuration: Release
Platform: x86


Can u help me in this regard?

Comment: This may not fix your problem, but when listing your artifact paths, it is better to specify the paths without a '/' in front of the path, like this: MyProject/bin/Release/*.* => PublishDir. The same also goes for the path to the solution file and most other file paths in TeamCity. Sometimes this can cause errors in the build.

From the information I have, this is the only issue I can see off the bat. Are the logs showing any warnings or errors involving publishing artifacts or is it not mentioned at all?